# Index Match a TextBox (ActiveX) via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run an Index Match on a Textbox (ActiveX Form) - which shows the Seller SKU to another Textbox (ActiveX Form) - which shows the product name upon clicking a "Search" button.

Essentially I want to return the Product name after entering the Seller SKU from a database in another worksheet.

```vb
Private Sub searchbtn_Click()

Set ref = Sheets("Reference Sheet")
ref.Activate
Set rgFound = Range("B:B").Find(SellerSKU.Value)

If rgFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Product not found"
    
ElseIf rgFound <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Seller SKU found in: " & rgFound.Row
    
    Description.Text = Cells(rgFound.Row, 1)
    MsgBox Description
    
End If

End Sub
```

However, RgFound is unable to find anything.

Comment: You need to specify more parameters of `Range.Find`, specifically `LookIn` and `LookAt`.

Comment: It helps if you show what it was that couldn't be found i.e. `MsgBox "'" & SellerSKU.Value & "' not found"` in case you have hidden spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using excel workbook function

```
    Private Sub searchbtn_Click()
        Dim MyTableArray As Range, SellerSKU As String
        Set MyTableArray = Sheets("Reference Sheet (SKU NAME)").Range("A:B")
        Me.Description.value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.SellerSKU, MyTableArray, 2, 0)

    End Sub
```